# Why does Sony Vegas Pro 9.0 render .MP4 horribly?

Tags: windows-7, mp4, rendering, sony-vegas

OS: Windows 7 Ult. 32bit

Latest version of Sony Vegas 9.0

Note: I have already tried uninstalling and reinstalling. No luck.

[Video Sample](http://tinypic.com/r/24vingw/6)

Comment: What do your system specs look like? Does it do all video this way? or just .MP4 ?

Comment: Just .MP4 for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I haven't seen it as bad as this.

If you have good output on other formats, I would check the export settings for .MP4 and make sure that you have the bitrate set high.

If all else fails, export to a good format and use [Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/) to transcode to MP4.

Comment: It seems that the .MP4 encoder in Vegas is broken, but I found another .MP4 encoder in Vegas called "Sony AVC" which allows u to encode to .MP4 and it works flawlessly. 

Also increasing the bitrate did help but not enough to reach perfect video.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Vegas 9 with **[K-Lite](http://www.free-codecs.com/download/K_lite_codec_pack.htm)** codec pack on Windows 7 x86 and have no such troubles. Make sure to select MP4 during setup when prompted which components you wish to install.

Comment: I am not prompted for the component installation.

Comment: @TheLakersHighlights - hmm, during the installation of k-lite you should see a screen similar to this one: http://img.brothersoft.com/screenshots/softimage/k/k-lite_codec_pack-246097-1244617782.jpeg

Comment: @Molly never got a screen like that. But I think I have found a workaround for my problem..

Comment: @TheLakersHighlights - very well.